# Target x button of a window title to an Button.Click event handler?

Tags: wpf, button, event-handling, window, click

I have in my window a button called btnExit which I handle its event.

I want that when I click the exit button (the red X in the right side) of the form, the event should be handled by the btnExit event.

Is this possible whithout need to use the OnExit or Closing etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's impossible.

I reported a suggestion [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=523119), please vote.